# How to resample nonperiodic signal with scipy?

Tags: scipy, signal-processing, downsampling

The documentation for [scipy.signal.resample](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.resample.html) says that it assumes the function is periodic. Is [interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d) the equivalent function for nonperiodic signals? If not, what is?

I've spent a lot of time searching for this and reading through other posts, but they all seem to assume you have a signal processing background; I'm from more of an algorithms background. I kind of understand what "Fourier methods" are, but shouldn't there be some kind of Fourier-based resampler for finite-length signals? (Perhaps using a DFT, etc.)

Comment: From your description of the problem, I think `interp1d` is likely what you want.  It's hard to be definitive without example data and a more thorough description of what you're trying to achieve.